# Keyboard volume shortcuts in XUBUNTU don't work

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, xfce, shortcuts

I have a Logitech K270 but I can't get the volume button shortcuts to work. 
Actually when I click them, I see the popup on the top left of the window but the volume is not changed...

```
g@g-on-linux:~/LendLib$ uname -a
Linux g-on-linux 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running Xubuntu - Xfce 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the best way to do so, I found that I was over-complicating things :D

You can just set the Media button like [here](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2011/08/control-volume-via-keyboard.html):

> 1. Go to System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts
> 2. Click on Sound and Media.
> 3. Assign Appropriate Keys to shortcuts for Volume up, down and mute.

If it doesn't work for you, do reply! (And if it does.. :)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have these menus/settings, this how-to is a bit outdated.. (so basically there's no "sound/media" category, all I get is a list of shortcuts with an add possibility but you have to type the command yourself.. and again, hitting the buttons actually does show something but the volume is not changed..

Comment: and the second method didn't work either

Comment: Than perhaps it's a bug within XFCE itself :(

Comment: Is there not a way to change volume and other settings in the command line (Terminal actually) ?? Why can't these be used to "Add" a new shortcut there? I am having similar problem just that I want to use other keys for volume and other things too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Shortcuts]

If you want to use different keys from the default ones, you can add this to your keyboard shortcuts:

> Go to 
>   **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**
>
> volume up -> `amixer -c 0 set PCM 2dB+`
>
> volume down -> `amixer -c 0 set PCM 2dB-`

If amixer is not installed... install it.

```
sudo apt-get install amixer
```